# Slow (high latency) upon queries with sort mongoDB

Tags: codeigniter, mongodb, php-mongodb

I am currently migrating from couchdb to mongodb, still learning this stuff and have a problem anytime I do some queries with sorting in my webpage.
I am using codeigniter as the framework and using [alexbilbie](https://github.com/alexbilbie/codeigniter-mongodb-library/tree/v2) lib for mongodb php library.

So, here is my problem:
I intend to do queries from sensors in a room that updated each second (thus, already saved thousands docs in collection) and to get each latest sensor value I use this query from model:

```
function mongoGetDocLatestDoc($sensorid){
    $doc = $this->mongo_db->where(array('SensorId'=>$sensorid))->limit(1)->order_by(array('_id'=>'DESC'))->get('my_mongo');
    return $doc;

}
```

if I called this with my controller, it took a lot of time to process the query and even worse if I change the sort by timestamp. and it is double the latency each time I called this again  for the second sensor, let alone I have more than 10 sensors that need this query in the same page. Am I doing it wrong or there is some more efficient way to get the latest data from collection?

edit:
@Sammaye : I tried making an index based on your suggestion and here is the explain generated after I executed the query:

```
"cursor" : "BtreeCursor timestamp_desc",
    "nscanned" : 326678,
    "nscannedObjects" : 326678,
    "n" : 50,
    "millis" : 4402,
    "nYields" : 7,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "indexBounds" : {
            "timestamp" : [
                    [
                            {
                                    "$maxElement" : 1
                            },
                            {
                                    "$minElement" : 1
                            }
                    ]
            ]
    }
```

as per comparison, this explain the first query without using index (that executed faster) :

```
"cursor" : "BasicCursor",
    "nscanned" : 385517,
    "nscannedObjects" : 385517,
    "n" : 50,
    "millis" : 1138,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "indexBounds" : {

    }
```

Comment: What does the indexes look like?

Comment: forgive me for my lack of knowledge. but my index only based on default provided by mongodb. which is by {"_id":1}  maybe this explains why it took time to sort it using timestamp since it has not indexed yet. but still even using _id to sort, I could not have a satisfying time latency.

Comment: You will to add compound index on sensorid and _id to make this efficient. The index would look like {"sensorid": 1, "_id": -1}, which is first sensorid ascending order and _id decending order. See the following page for docs on compound indexes in MongoDB: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#compound-indexes

Comment: Can you add a `explain()` to this post for your query?

Comment: why are you calling multiple times for multiple sensors?  You should only query once giving the list of sensorIds using the {$in:[ ]} operator.  Then make sure you have a compound index on {"sensorId":1, _id:1} and it should be one call that's fast and returns all the documents you need to have on that page.  If you need to sort by timestamp replace _id in that index with timestamp.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky: since actually my collection contains more sensor from other rooms as well and I only required to query some sensors. which the value of each sensor I intend to represent it into a separate widget.

Comment: @Sammaye : I tried making an index based on your suggestion and here is the explain generated after I executed the query:

Comment: I did not recommend any index but ok, you have made an index on `timestamp` but you don't use the `timestamp` field in your query, how will that index help for your query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay thank you all for your great response :) Here is my finding after trying with indexes:

1. Update the mongodb to the latest version. I found this slightly improve my query. I am updating from default 2.0.3 that provided as default in ubuntu 12.04.02 to mongodb version 2.4.3
2. Build indexes/compound indexes based exactly on how you mostly needed in your query. as an example, in my question, my query based on `SensorId` and `_id`: DESCENDING so the best strategy to optimize my query would be something like :
   `db.your_collection.ensureIndex({ "SourceId" : 1,  "_id" : -1 },{ "name" : "sourceid_idx", "background" : true });`
   or in other case if I needed it based on timestamp:

   `db.your_collection.ensureIndex({ "SourceId" : 1, "timestamp" : -1 },{ "name" : "source_idx", "background" : true });`

I found a very good explanation about mongodb indexes [here](http://blog.mongolab.com/2012/06/cardinal-ins/)

Hope this will help other people that stumbled upon similar problem...